# Sorting enum array more efficiently

Tags: c#, enums, performance

Currently I have some buttons on my Winform that need to be disabled/enabled at various points depending what the user clicks.

The first draft I made was

```
button1.Enabled = false;
button2.Enabled = false;
```

To disable 2 buttons, which is obviously a horrible way of doing this, as there are currently a lot more than 2 and possibly more to come as this is still in development. So I need to have a way of easily changing a selection of buttons on the form.

Then I came up with this

```
private enum Buttons { Button1, Button2 } // etc with all buttons - that are named :)

private void DisableButtons(params Buttons[] buttons)
{
    foreach (Buttons button in buttons)
    {
        switch (button)
        {
            case Buttons.Button1:
                button1.Enabled = false;
                break;
            case Buttons.Button2:
                button2.Enabled = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which I still wasn't overly happy with. I could scrap the `switch-case` and `foreach` for

```
private void DisableButtons(params Buttons[] buttons)
{
    button1.Enabled = buttons.Contains(Buttons.Button1) ? false : true;
}
```

for each button but I just think there must be a better way.

Any ideas on how I could do this more efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Could you reiterate what is "obviously horrible" with the first snippet?

Comment: @Jodrell Say I have 10 or more buttons, I think everyone would agree that doing `buttonx.Enabled = false` for each one is **NOT** a good way of doing this.

Comment: your third option will only disable a single button.

Comment: @Asif Yes, but I would initially add all my buttons in there, and then pass the function the buttons I want to change.

Comment: I don't think declaring and `enum` or `array` makes the logic any clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten your last code line to:

```
button1.Enabled = !buttons.Contains(Buttons.Button1);
```

**Alternative solution**

Or you can use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property of each button to set a enum value for each button.

```
button1.Tag = Buttons.Button1;
button2.Tag = Buttons.Button2;
button3.Tag = Buttons.Button3;
// etc
```

Than you can do it for all buttons in a for loop:

```
var buttons = <all buttons, todo>
foreach (var button in buttons) {
    button.Enabled = !button.Contains((Buttons)button.Tag));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you don't infact want to make a function that flexibly enables and disables any combination of buttons because you don't yet percieve how your `Form` will work. Granted, this may save you a few lines of code but, it won't impart any contextual information to the next developer that maintians your code. Neither will it run faster than directly setting the state of the controls.

I woud make a single function that is called whenever your `Form` changes state, that takes all possible parameters that pertain to your `Form`s state. Then I would decode those parameters and explicitly setup the state of the controls on the form, by name, in a single pass, using tranditional `switch` and `if` statments.

This central function will make it clear to you and future developers how the state of you form changes and how controls are expected to behave. It won't slow down the performance of you code with an unecessary level of abstraction.